# Why does this code give an error saying the function is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I keep running into this same problem whenever I use a library

The read-me on GitHub says toHyperE() is one of the functions

It displays an error saying 'function not defined'

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "OmegaNum.js-master/OmegaNum.js">
</head>
<body>
<script>
var variable = toHyperE(19);
console.log(variable);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: "the same problem": what's the problem? What error do you get?

Comment: JS OmegaNum.js-master/OmegaNum.js. has to be in the same folder/same name. Use <script src = "./OmegaNum.js"> for safe side

Comment: One problem with the above is that you don't have any closing `</script>` tag. Some end tags are optional, but not `</script>`. Separately, look at your web console and network panel to see that you're really getting the script loaded, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid (your <script> tag has no ending tag). Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="OmegaNum.js-master/OmegaNum.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var variable = toHyperE(19);
console.log(variable);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be the answer to the question, since the question says the OP is getting an error saying the function is undefined. They won't be getting that error if the second script tag isn't run. (Also, you need a closing `</script>` on the second script tag.)

Comment: By the way, that's not my point. Even if you do add it then it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SparklestheUnicorn your script source must not be valid then